# Is 'for' not actually lazy in clojure?

Tags: clojure, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

```
(take 2 (for [x (range 10)
              :let [_ (println x)]
              :when (even? x)] x))
>> (* 0
* 1
* 2
* 3
* 4
* 5
* 6
* 7
* 8
* 9
0 2)
```

I assumed I was just being remarkably dense. But no, it turns out that Clojure actually evaluates the first 32 elements of any lazy sequence (if available). Ouch.

I had a `for` with a recursive call in the `:let`. I was very curious as to why computation seemed to be proceeding in a breadth first rather than depth first fashion. It seems that computation (although, to be fair, not memory) was exploding as I kept going down all the upper branches of the recursive tree. Clojure's 32-chunking was forcing breadth first evaluation, even though the logical intent of the code was depth first.

Anyway, is there any simple way to force 1-chunking rather than 32-chunking of lazy sequences?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Michaes Fogus [has written a blog entry on disabling this behavior by providing a custom ISeq implementation](http://blog.fogus.me/2010/01/22/de-chunkifying-sequences-in-clojure/).

To steal shamelessly from [the modified version by Colin Jones](https://gist.github.com/717761):

```
(defn seq1 [#^clojure.lang.ISeq s]
  (reify clojure.lang.ISeq
    (first [_] (.first s))
    (more [_] (seq1 (.more s)))
    (next [_] (let [sn (.next s)] (and sn (seq1 sn))))
    (seq [_] (let [ss (.seq s)] (and ss (seq1 ss))))
    (count [_] (.count s))
    (cons [_ o] (.cons s o))
    (empty [_] (.empty s))
    (equiv [_ o] (.equiv s o))))
```

A simpler approach is given [in The Joy of Clojure](http://joyofclojure.com/):

```
(defn seq1 [s]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [[x] (seq s)]
       (cons x (seq1 (rest s))))))
```

Comment: Thank you! This had me stumped for two hours. I couldn't figure out why
(take 1 (map some-func [1 2 3 4]))
evaluates some-func for all 4 elements... I must say, it wasn't obvious why that was happening, from reading the docs on "map" and "take"

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in your title, no, `for` is not lazy.  [However](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/for), it:

> Takes a vector of one or more 
>   binding-form/collection-expr pairs, each followed by zero or more 
>   modifiers, and **yields a lazy sequence of evaluations of expr.**

(emphasis mine)

So [what's going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824501/how-does-clojures-laziness-interact-with-calls-to-java-impure-code#comment9537444_7824547)?

> basically Clojure always evaluates strictly. Lazy seqs
>   basically use the same tricks as python with their generators etc.
>   Strict evals in lazy clothes.

In other words, `for` *eagerly* returns a *lazy* sequence.  Which won't be evaluated until you ask for it, and will be chunked.